# Hartshorne 14.5 Give necessary and sufficient conditions on the field F for the given configuration to exist

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm working through Hartshorne's Euclid and Beyond and have hit a wall with the following question, 14.5: 
"For each of he following problems, assume that you are working in the Cartesian plane PI over a field F of characteristic 0. Give necessary and sufficient conditions on the field F for the given configuration to exist. Assume that all lines that appear to be parallel are parallel, and apparent right angles are right angles."

He gives the solution as (13)^(1/2)

I've set up my axes as usual, and unit points at F=(0,1) vertically and B=(1,0) horizontally. I've been focused on using HC || IG, equating the slopes, etc. But it's unclear to me where he's getting his result.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEw0a.png)

[Set up of axes and points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INKPl.png)

Comment: Please include the full statement of the problem in your question: right now the "given configuration" is nowhere to be found in your post, which makes writing good answers very difficult.

Comment: Added as links. Hartshorne's statement as well as the setup I'm working with. Thanks... first post and had to sort out how to add graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the letter names of the points in your image, but I'll rename one distance: let $I=(0,1+b)$, which makes $0<b<1$.

Look at the three similar triangles, those with hypotenuse highlighted in pink in your uploaded image. These are $EIL,IAG,HKC$. $IAG$ has legs $1+b$ and $a$, $HKC$ has legs $1$ 
 and $1-a$, and $EIL$ has legs $1-b$ and $b$. Together, this gives us the three equations $\frac{1+b}{a}=\frac{1}{1-a}=\frac{1-b}{b}$. Using $\frac{1}{1-a}=\frac{1-b}{b}$, we may solve for $a=\frac{1-2b}{1-b}$. Using $\frac{1+b}{a}=\frac{1-b}{b}$, we may solve for $a=\frac{b(b+1)}{1-b}$.

Putting these together, we have $\frac{b(b+1)}{1-b}=\frac{1-2b}{1-b}$, or $b^2+b=1-2b$, or $b^2+3b-1=0$. This equation is solved by $b=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and no other values, so this configuration occurs exactly when $b=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$ is in the field we're working over.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! I wasn't even looking at the relationship of the triangles. I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Glad to have helped you! If you find this response answers your question, it is customary to click on the green checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it. If you find it useful, it is also customary to upvote the answer using the up arrow next to it.

Comment: I clicked the green check, but it's not allowing me to upvote. Thanks for the follow up!